# Chart js Bar Time Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

There are two ways to add data in the bar time chart

1. When We add Dates in the labels and pass y as data in datasets
2. Add as an (x,y) pair in datasets directly

1st one works perfectly while 2nd one doesn't render anything

```js
var barChartData = {
   labels: [moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(), moment().add(2, 'd').toDate(), moment().add(3, 'd').toDate(), moment().add(4, 'd').toDate(), moment().add(5, 'd').toDate(), moment().add(6, 'd').toDate(), moment().add(7, 'd').toDate()],
   datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
    data: [
     Math.random()*100,
     Math.random()*100,
     Math.random()*100,
     Math.random()*100,
     Math.random()*100,
     Math.random()*100,
          Math.random()*100
        ]
      }]    
  }
```

```js
var barChartData = {
   datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
    data: [
     { x: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
     { x: moment().add(2, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
     { x: moment().add(3, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
     { x: moment().add(4, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
     { x: moment().add(5, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
     { x: moment().add(6, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
     { x: moment().add(7, 'd').toDate(), y: Math.random()*100 },
    ]
   }]

  };
```

Is there Something Wrong That I m doing Or is It a Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All type of charts doesn't support 'cartesian axes' . Bar chart is one of those types , it supports  'radial axes'.

If you want to use both (x,y) axis in your chart choose different type . Use bubble/Scatter charts for  (x,y) pair .

Read this article , you will get more information here : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/